# Gradle not finding Jar in libs folder after updating *.jar file

Tags: gradle, jar, libs

I created a *.jar file and included it as a library in another project that uses Gradle. It was working perfectly fine, until I added a new method to the *.jar, replaced it in the libs folder, and tried to refresh the gradle dependencies. Now gradle cannot find the *.jar to import.

I added this line to gradle.dependencies dependency block, which worked fine at first:

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

I then added an empty void method to original *.jar, rebuilt the artifact, replaced it in the "libs" folder, and refreshed gradle dependencies. Now it says it cannot find it, even though I can see it import it if I do a complete clean/refresh?

Comment: I managed to fix this by invalidating caches and restarting IDE (Intellij)